# How do I override `toString` in my derived class and use the private instance variables from the base class?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

This is my base class `Vehicle` with `private` instance variables.

```
public class Vehicle {
    private int numPassengers;
    private String colour;

    Vehicle(int passengers, String colour) {
        this.numPassengers = passengers;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return colour + " " + numPassengers + " passengers";
    }
}
```

Note that there are no accessor methods in this class and that I **cannot** edit this class in any way.

I have a derived class `Car` with one additional instance variable `numberOfDoors`

```
public class Car extends Vehicle
{   
    private int numberOfDoors;

    public Car(String newColour, int newNumberOfPassengers, int newNumberOfDoors)
    {
        super(newNumberOfPassengers, newColour);
        this.numberOfDoors = newNumberOfDoors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return colour + " " + numPassengers + " passengers " + numberOfDoors + " doors";
    }
}
```

I can edit this class as I desire and I am aware of the different constructor method signature.

Obviously, the return statement in `toString()` is giving me issues because this class has no access to the `private` instance variable in `Vehicle`. I know that if the instance variables in `Vehicle` has package/protected access, this wouldn't be an issue, but either my instructor has made a mistake or we are supposed to come up with a workaround.

Is there a way around this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sub-class can't access the private members of the super-class, unless you have getters for them.

What you could you is :

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " " + numberOfDoors + " doors";
}
```

Comment: Can you simply just append to the return of the method of the base class like that? Awesome. So simple.

Comment: Also, I'd like to thank you for your incredibly hasty and efficient response.